# How to detect target on video feed from assets folder or URL using Augmented Reality sdk, instead of Camera

Tags: android, augmented-reality

I want to detect the target on a saved video feed or URL video. For this, I have been looking around AR SDKs But found no sdk to support this. All SDKs are supporting the target detection on live camera only But not on saved video or URL streaming video.

Is there any way to do this?
Which SDK support this feature?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any SDK doing this natively but instead of using camera frames you need to write a piece of code that reads the stored video (or connects to a given URL) and use those frames. In other words, all you need to do is replace the input source. Therefore I assume that any SDK that allows you to provide your own frames would be suited for your need.

Comment: Yeh! But SDKs provide video playback But don't perform AR on that. And I am to perform AR on the video feeds.:(

Comment: You can augment the stored video by using the above explanation.. :o

Comment: But I didn't find any way in any SDK to change the input source.